# What is the easiest way to strip the shared library built by the python-based project?

Tags: python, distutils

When compiling a Python C-API project using `distutils` or `setuptools`, it results in unstripped `.so` executables, which are considerably larger in size.
Is there a way to easily strip them without calling `strip -s` manually on the executable? For example,
is there an option for this in `setup.py`?

Comment: what do you mean by "unstripped executables"?

Comment: @wotanii https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip

Answer (score 5):

Set (and export) environment variable `LDFLAGS=-s` before build steps, i.e.

```
export LDFLAGS=-s
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@phd mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51936661/4576519), you can skip the manual stripping step by specifying the `LDFLAGS=-s` environment variable. If you want to automatically do this from `setup.py`, simply add the following at the start:

```py
import os
os.environ["LDFLAGS"] = "-s"
```